Bookmark whose URL is loaded from the site
There is a website that has a certain button, the href of which changes every week. I need a bookmark that will redirect me to the URL in this href.
I tried to use a Bookmarklet, but it doesn't seem to work, as I need the page to load completely at the time the JavaScript code is executed.
Here's what i have:
javascript:(function(){
    window.location.href = "https://rasp.tpu.ru/site/department.html?id=7950&cource=1";
    window.location.href = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).find(element => element.href.includes('gruppa_42148')).href 
})();

I tried to wait for the website to load:
javascript:(function(){
    window.location.href = "https://rasp.tpu.ru/site/department.html?id=7950&cource=1";
    window.addEventListener('load', function () { window.location.href = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).find(element => element.href.includes('gruppa_42148')).href })
})();

But it's not working. As i understand, this is simply not possible with a bookmarklet, you can not run a script in one page, then go to another and try to get the content of this page in order to continue executing something in the script.
I was also thinking about writing a script in Tampermonkey that will run only when I go to this site from a certain bookmark, but again I have no idea how to do this.

So run the bookmarklet after the page has loaded, or add a mutation observer to the bookmarklet

Could you create a page at your website that simply sends a redirect to the current page's URL?

@Barmar That's not my website. I put it wrong, sorry, not my first language.

What part of doing it with Tampermonkey don't you understand? When you create a tampermonkey script, you can specify the web pages that it should run on, so you can make it just for the website. I think it can then use location.href=new_href to redirect to the updated href.

@Barmar I don't need to always run a script on a website. Sometimes I need to visit it without being automatically redirected. Therefore, I need to run script only when I access this website through a bookmark, which I do not know how to check.

That does seem tricky. I'm not sure how you would script something like that.

can you post the site url?

@GTK Here, link

@JohnSnow which button changes every week?

@mplungjan Tried the mutation observer, but it doesn't seem to work. And about running the bookmarklet after loading the page. I can do this by opening a web page first and then clicking on the bookmarklet, but that's not what I want. I want to do it in one go, just by clicking on a bookmark. Waiting for the page to load in the script doesn't work either.

@GTK The one that says "8ПМ4Л" or it "8PM4L" in English i think. There's a bunch of buttons with numbers and letters, they're all basically the same. All of them redirect you to a weekly schedule, the current URL of which changes every week.

@JohnSnow it seems like only the week number changes? does this gruppa_42148 change?

@GTK No, the gruppa_42148 does not change, but the year also change occasionally.

A bookmarklet runs in the scope of the page. The page is no more after the first window.location.href, so that will never work. You can only do those two after each other using a browser script or a server proxy

There is actually a link on this page that seems to be a server redirect link to the calendar page:
https://go.tpu.ru/VJSufWbM > https://rasp.tpu.ru/redirect/kalendar.html?hash=1Xyu9g > https://rasp.tpu.ru/gruppa_42148/2024/1/view.html

You can also do what you want with tampermonkey:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         bookmark
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2024-09-04
// @description  .
// @author       You
// @match        https://rasp.tpu.ru/site/department.html?id=7950&cource=1
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=tpu.ru
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


if (location.hash === '#bookmark'){
    const a = document.querySelector('a[href*=gruppa_42148]');
    a && location.replace(a.href);
}

this will only redirect if the url includes the hash #bookmark.
and use this as the bookmark url:
https://rasp.tpu.ru/site/department.html?id=7950&cource=1#bookmark

Thanks, both worked. But the first one is faster, since only one page is loads, gonna use this one.

And can I ask. How did you find this link. Did you just looked around the website or there is some way to track it?

@JohnSnow yes, just looked around the calendar page, clicked 09.04.04 Программная инженерия, then under groups you can find 8ПМ4Л
